# What is the Root Pane in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

this question was asked : [Disposing JFrame by clicking from an inner JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358296/disposing-jframe-by-clicking-from-an-inner-jpanel)

and people provided answers that i didn't quite understand 
so the question is what does this actually do :

```
((Window) getRootPane().getParent()).dispose();
```

could some one explain it to me?

Comment: Is this a problem of programming? IMO it is a problem of understanding. I think there are documentations for the programming language. Read the fine manuals.

Comment: The best way to find a JComponent's window is with its [getTopLevelAncestor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getTopLevelAncestor--) method.  The second best way is with [SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor-java.awt.Component-).  A JRootPane is not always a direct child of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets the `JPanel` in which the `JButton` is on.
 Then it gets the parent of the `JPanel`, which is the `JFrame`. 
Finally it disposes the `JFrame` using `dispose()`.

See [Root Pane Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RootPaneContainer.html) for more information

Comment: that was helpful  got it

Comment: @M.Helmy Glad I could help

Comment: @M.Helmy If you feel this answer is correct could you please accept it as an answer by clicking on the tick underneath the up and down arrows next to the answer